# mixing pygobject (python wrapper) and C GTK+

Tags: python, c, gtk, pygobject

I'm interested in being able to mix python and C code with GTK+. I'm capable of creating shared object libs in C and accessing them from python. I'm wondering how to gain access to the GtkWidget pointer from a pygobject class and pass that into the C function. Another possibility is to create the GtkWidget in a C function, but I would still need a pointer to the parent widget I want to pack_start to etc. I would like to do OpenGL code in C for the GLArea widget and pack it into a pygobject Gtk.Box(). I know it's possible to use the python wrapper for OpenGL.

Comment: I'm also interested in this, were you able to accomplish something?